# How to generate polkadot, filecoin address from xpub

Tags: cryptography, polkadot, filecoin

I have a xpub(extended public key) right now,and I want use this xpub to generate a polkadot address. so in my wallet I can use this address receive dot coin.

```
function xpubToDotAddress(xpub){
   ...logic here;
   return address;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far and give some more information as the question as is quite unclear.

Comment: I was building a HD Wallet, and derivate some xpub to create wallet for different coins. polkadot is one of the coins. and I can't find any recourses to generate address from this xpub?